# button wrapped in React class doesn't adopt styles

Tags: reactjs

If I render a button like this in my app.jsx file

`<button className="myflatbutton">Click For Fun</button>`

then it adopts the styles that I've created for my buttons in my app.css file, namely, the buttons aren't the ugly default button that the browser gives you. However, if I wrap the same input type=button in a React class like this

```
var MyReactButton = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
       return(
         <input type="button" onClick={this.props.onButtonClicked} value={this.props.Title} />
      )
    }
});
```

it ignores the global button styles in app.css

```
button, .button, input[type=submit]{
   color: #fff;
   border-radius: 0px;
   border: none;
  //many more omitted for brevity
}
```

Is there a way to get a button wrapped in a React class to use those styles without writing them out each time I apply a react class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, isn't the css wrong?  A fiddle would definitely help here.

Your react component is `input type="button"` whereas your css is `input[type=submit]`.

Comment: ok, thank you. I'll be back with a fiddle if the problem wasn't what you indicated, otherwise will accept your answer

Comment: Looks like that's all it was. nice!